# How to add ‘Click to edit this widget’ button to Wordpress widgets?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Using the twenty twenty theme, I can see a button that makes you be able to edit the plugin content.

The button am talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4nnz.jpg

I know exactly how to create widgets, no problem with that, I just want to know how to add that edit button because when I create widgets that button doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer:
First you should insclude 'before_widget' and 'after_widget.
Then you have put: add_theme_support('customize-selective-refresh-widgets');